# Matriz espiral no funciona Java

Tags: java, matrices

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que hice para recorrer la matriz espiral, pero recorre la matriz de otra manera

> ```
> 2000021 
> 1970022 
> 1860123
> 1714131224 
> 1600025
> ```

```
public class caracol {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
int[][] matriz = new int[5][5];
int n=5;
int nlimite= n-1;
int inicio = 0;
int c=1;
while(c<=(n*n)){

            for (int i = inicio+2; i<=nlimite-1; i++) //baja
            {
                matriz[i][nlimite-1] = c++;

            }

            for (int i = inicio+2; i>=inicio+1; i--) ///izquierda
            {
                matriz[nlimite-1][i] = c++;

            }

            for (int i = nlimite-1; i>=inicio+1; i--) //sube
            {
                matriz[i][inicio+1] = c++;

            }


            for (int i = inicio+1; i>=nlimite-1; i++) //derecha
            {
                matriz[inicio+1][i] = c++;

            }

           for (int i = inicio+1; i<=nlimite; i++) //baja
            {
                matriz[i][nlimite] = c++;

            }

             for (int i = nlimite-1; i>=inicio; i--) ///izquierda
            {
                matriz[nlimite-1][i] = c++;

            }

            for (int i = nlimite; i>=inicio; i--) //sube
            {
                matriz[i][inicio] = c++;

            }

            for (int i = inicio; i>=nlimite; i++) //derecha
            {
                matriz[inicio][i] = c++;

            }  

            for (int i = inicio; i<=nlimite; i++) //baja
            {
                matriz[i][nlimite] = c++;

            }
            nlimite=nlimite-1;
inicio = inicio+1;
}
for(int x=0;x<n;x++){ /*Mostrar la matriz en pantalla*/
System.out.println();
for(int y=0;y<n;y++){
System.out.print(matriz[x][y]);
}
}
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Que tal @ives. Buen dia.

Bueno, no me parece tan conveniente tener multiples ciclos para realizar la misma tarea, como es el caso por ejemplo el de 'bajar' las posiciones en el array.

Pero bien, partiendo de la base que la matriz tendrá igual numero tanto de filas como de columnas y ademas del recorrido que aparece en la foto (*iniciando desde el centro hacia afuera*), te aclararé el proceso con código comentado, espero ser lo suficientemente descriptivo en él para que puedas analizarlo sin problemas.

Mira:

```
public void caracol( int tam ) {
    boolean abajo = true, izquierda = false, arriba = false; //Direcciones.
    boolean es_par = tam % 2 == 0; //Array2D par o impar?.
    int x = es_par ? tam / 2 - 1 : tam / 2;
    //Posicion inicial de 'x' sera la mitad MENOS 1 de las FILAS si el array es par, sino estara exactamente en la fila de la mitad.
    int y = tam / 2; //Posicion inicial de 'y' siempre en la columna del medio.
    int[][] mat = new int[ tam ][ tam ]; //Instancia del nuevo Array2D.

    for( int k = 1; k <= tam * tam; k++ ) { //Inicio de ciclo de 1 a total de posiciones en el array.
      mat[ x ][ y ] = k; //Contador almacenado en la coordenada.

      if( abajo ) { //Direccion hacia abajo.
        if( ( x - y > 0 && ! es_par ) || ( x - y >= 0 && es_par ) ) {
        //Condicional para diferenciar entre Array2D impar o par. [para impares se excluye la diagonal principal (x - y = 0) ].
          abajo = false; //Cambio de direccion y actualizacion de coordenada 'x' o 'y'.
          izquierda = true;
          y --;
        } else {
          x ++;
        }
      } else if( izquierda ) {// Direccion hacia la izquierda.
        if( x + y == mat.length - 1 ) {// Si se llega a la diagonal secundaria [x + y = tamano - 1], redireccionar.
          izquierda = false;// Cambio de direccion y actualizacion de coordenada 'x' o 'y'.
          arriba = true;
          x --;
        } else {
          y --;
        }
      } else if( arriba ) {// Direccion hacia arriba.
        if( ( x - y <= 0 && ! es_par ) || ( x - y < 0 && es_par ) ) {
        //Condicional para diferenciar entre Array2D impar o par. [para impares ahora se incluye la diagonal principal (x - y = 0) ].
          arriba = false;// Cambio de direccion y actualizacion de coordenada 'x' o 'y'.
          y ++;
        } else {
          x --;
        }
      } else if( x + y == mat.length - 1 ) {// [default] Direccion hacia la derecha hasta tocar la diagonal secundaria [x + y = tamano - 1].
        abajo = true;// Cambio de direccion y actualizacion de coordenada 'x' o 'y'.
        x ++;
      } else {
        y ++;
      }
    }// Fin de ciclo de 1 a total de posiciones en Array2D.

    // Impresion en consola.
    for( int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++ ) {
      System.out.println();
      for( int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++ ) {
        System.out.print( mat[ i ][ j ] + "\t" );
      }
    }
  }
```

- **Matriz de orden 5:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- **Matriz de orden 6:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una forma de hacerlo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MatrizCaracol { 

private int[][] matriz; 
private int dimension; 
private int valores; 

public MatrizCaracol(int n) { 
    matriz = new int[n][n]; 
    dimension = n; 
    valores = n * n; 
    rellenar(); 
} 

private void rellenar() { 
    int fila, vuelta = 0, col, val = 1; 
    while (val <= valores) { 

        for (col = vuelta, fila = vuelta; val <= valores && col < dimension - 1 - vuelta; col++) { 
            matriz[fila][col] = val; 
            val++; 
        } 

        for (col = dimension - 1 - vuelta, fila = vuelta; val <= valores && fila < dimension - 1 - vuelta; fila++) { 
            matriz[fila][col] = val; 
            val++; 
        } 

        for (col = dimension - 1 - vuelta, fila = dimension - 1 - vuelta; val <= valores && col > vuelta; col--) { 
            matriz[fila][col] = val; 
            val++; 
        } 

        for (col = vuelta, fila = dimension - 1 - vuelta; val <= valores && fila > vuelta; fila--) { 
            matriz[fila][col] = val; 
            val++; 
        } 

        if (dimension % 2 != 0 && val == valores) { 
            col = fila = dimension / 2; 
            matriz[fila][col] = val; 
            val++; 
        } 
        vuelta++; 
    } 
} 

@Override 
public String toString() { 
    String out = ""; 

      for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) { 
      out+=(Arrays.toString(matriz[i])); 
      out+="\n"; 
    } 
    return out; 
} 

public static void main(String[] args){ 
    System.out.println(new MatrizCaracol(4)); 
}
```

}